# Hibernate persistent object behavior

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I was trying to learn about different states of objects in Hibernate. I tried the following and could not find an explanation to the behavior shown. Can anyone help?

Here is what I am trying to do: Insert a new record in Employee table (empId being primary key). In the same transaction, update the newly added record (using a query, modifying empName). Then when I am checking empName property of the persistent object it continues to show the old empName value. Being a persistent object, I expected it to reflect the change made in the database. I could not understand why it didn't. (My hibernate config file has everything set to default except for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property set as update)
However, after doing update, when I set the empName of the persistent object with value returned by getEmpName (which displays as the old empName value by sysout), the final data in the table shows the new empName value (i.e the one I updated using hql). Please refer to the code for this:

```
Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();

    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    e1.setEmpId(1);
    e1.setEmpName("Jack");
    e1.setEmpAge(25);
    session.save(e1);
    System.out.println("before: "+e1.getEmpName()); //prints Jack
    session.createQuery("update Employee set empName = \'Jack_new\' where id=1").executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("after: "+e1.getEmpName()); //prints Jack
    e1.setEmpName(e1.getEmpName()); //should update database
    tx.commit(); //sets empName value to Jack_new, as seen in table
    System.out.println("last: "+e1.getEmpName()); //prints Jack
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct):

> Manipulating data directly in the database (using the SQL Data
>   Manipulation Language (DML) the statements: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
>   will not affect in-memory state.

As you use the following direct DML  to update,

```
session.createQuery("update Employee set empName = \'Jack_new\' where id=1").executeUpdate();
```

it will bypasses the Hibernate persistence context (and all caches). So ,although the `empName` is update to `Jack_new` in the DB actually , its instance in the persistence context still keeps the old value .

You can use `session.refresh(e1);` to re-read the values for the `e1` from the underlying database such that `e1.empName` will be refreshed to `Jack_new`.

Normally , we don't manually write the UPDATE statements to perform update .Just set the updated values to the properties of the persisted instances. During flushing , hibernate will do the dirty check , generate and issue the corresponding update SQL automatically  to update those dirty instances.

---

(Reply to the comment):

> However, just before doing tx.commit() I am setting e1.empName to old
>   value (that is value returned by e1.getEmpName()).Still the final
>   value seen in the database is the new value.?

```
/**e1 become persisted after save()**/
 session.save(e1);

/**e1.empName is updated to new value in the DB , but as the direct DML
 will not affect in-memory state , e1.empName in the java side 
 still keeps the old value***/
 session.createQuery("update Employee set empName = \'Jack_new\' where id=1").executeUpdate();

/** As you only set `e1.empName` to its original value , the values of `e1` do 
not have any changes. Thus , during the flushing (which occurs at the moment 
before `commit()`) , hibernate will consider  that `e1` is not dirty  and 
hence no update SQL will be generated and issued to update e1 . 
***/
e1.setEmpName(e1.getEmpName());
```

So , the outcome is that `Jack_new` is saved in the DB.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Dmitry and Ken. Helped me understand most of the issue. However, just before doing tx.commit() I am setting e1.empName to old value (that is value returned by e1.getEmpName()).Still the  final value seen in the database is the new value.?

Answer (score 1):

you are executing a direct query against the database changing a field's value behind hibernate's back.  When you do this, you object will not magically changed it's saved value, which is the original name.  So when you do "e1.setEmpName(e1.getEmpName());" you are setting the name back to the original value.

Comment: Thanks. However, just before doing tx.commit() I am setting e1.empName to old value (that is value returned by e1.getEmpName()).Still the final value seen in the database is the new value.?